# Python - how to get edit box value in others module?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

in general, i want connect to the database selected by users.

i using 2 module, dblogin.py and xconn.py

dblogin.py is the gui for user to setting the desired dataname, and xconn.py is the connection to the postgresql

the problem is i can't get the value of dbedit in dblogin.py 
how i can fix it?

thanks b4 for the answer.... Gbu all......

Regards, 
ide

dblogin.py

```
class dblog(QDialog):
def __init__(self):
    super(dblog, self).__init__()
    self.dblabel = QLabel('Database Name')
    self.dbedit = QLineEdit('')

    #create button        
    ...

    #set layout in grid

    #action for button
    self.connect(self.connectbutton, SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.connectaction)

def connectaction(self):                
    self._data = self.dbedit.text()
    if self._data == '':
        _msg = QMessageBox.information(self,'information','Nama Database harus diisi !',QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.dbedit.setFocus()
    else:
        try:
            xconn.getconn()
            _msg = QMessageBox.information(self,'information','Tunggu, Check database struktur!',QMessageBox.Ok)
        except:
            _msg = QMessageBox.information(self,'information','Database tidak ditemukan !',QMessageBox.Ok)
```

xconn.py

```
import psycopg2
import dblogin

def getconn():    
    _host = '127.0.0.1'
    _user = 'postgres'
    _pass = 'xxx'
    _data = dblogin.dblog.getdb()          

    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=_data, user=_user, password=_pass, host=_host)
    return conn
```

Comment: Is the problem in the `_data = dblogin.dblog.getdb()` line? How about `_data = dblogin.dblog.dbedit.text()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your QDialog class should begin with capiatlized letters class DBLog. You can use the standardbuttons:

```
    self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
```

To set the text from the QLineEdit as return value, reimplement the accept method:

```
    self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)

    def accept(self):
    self._data = self.dbedit.text()
    self.done(1)
```

Then in xconn create an instance od DBLog and only use the Dialog to get this value. Then from xconn.py do something like this:

```
    dblog = DBLog() # create an instance for your dialog
    if dblog:
         _data = dblog._data
    else:
         Dialog not accepted
```